# Child data does not display in query result - Using Apache Solr 4.8.1 with mySql

Tags: php, mysql, apache, solr

I am trying to use Apache SOLR for indexing my Mysql Database. The aim is to have solr handle all user related searches.

I am indexing the data as a parent child relationship as demonstrated in the tutorial ( http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Using_delta-import_command )

Basically i am trying to search a forum discussion. Where all post titles are stored in the table called "adda_topic" while all replies are stored in "adda_discussion" (where the first mesage is the message/content for the first post)

Here is my data-config.xml file

```
 <document name="forum_posts">  

        <entity name="forum_topics" pk="topic_id"

            query="SELECT *, 'forum' AS type FROM adda_topic"
            deltaImportQuery="SELECT *, 'forum' AS type FROM adda_topic WHERE topic_id = '${dataimporter.delta.topic_id}'"
            deltaQuery="SELECT topic_id FROM adda_topic WHERE topic_start_date > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}' ">   

           <field column="topic_id" name="id"/>
           <field column="topic_apt_id" name="apt_id"/>
           <field column="topic_owner_id" name="owner_id"/>
           <field column="type" name="type"/>          
           <field column="topic_name" name="title"/>
           <field column="topic_start_date" name="created_date"/>
           <field column="topic_filter_level" name="filter_level"/>

                <entity name="discussion" pk="discussion_topic_id" transformer="HTMLStripTransformer"

                    query="SELECT * FROM adda_discussion WHERE discussion_topic_id = '${forum_topics.topic_id}'"                        
                    deltaQuery="SELECT discussion_topic_id FROM adda_discussion WHERE discussion_date > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"                      
                    parentDeltaQuery="SELECT topic_id FROM adda_topic WHERE topic_id = '${discussion.discussion_topic_id}'">

                    <field column="discussion_id" name="child_ids"/>
                    <field column="discussion_text" name="content" stripHTML="true"/>

                </entity>

        </entity>

 </document>
```

as you can see. I am grouping the discussions under each title/topic. Ann all replies have the same topic_id as its foreign key.

The problem i am facing is that When i import the data. Only the first discussion is searchable. IF i search for text in any of the replies i do not get any results.

Am i doing this right ? some topics can have hundreds of replies to it. and none of the replies are getting indexed or stored at the moment.

How do i get the replies to be searchable as well ?

e.g. if this is sample data . .

- Test topic name here

  - Original reply/discussion for post here
  - additional reply one
  - Another reply two.

In the above case . I am able to search for "Test topic name here" and "Original reply/discussion for post here"

But i get zero results when i search for "additional reply one" or "Another reply two"

Comment: Guys ? any idea on how this could be fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i managed to fix it on my own. ( almost lost my sanity on this one )

Tried various combinations. finally interchanged the discussion entity with the topic entity. ( basically interchanged parent and child )

So i now index the topic entity for every discussion entity.

A kind of a weird approach, but it works.

here is the working config snippet. just in case it helps anyone in the future.

```
    <entity name="discussion" pk="discussion_id" transformer="HTMLStripTransformer"
        query="SELECT * FROM adda_discussion"
        deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM adda_discussion WHERE discussion_id = '${dataimporter.delta.discussion_id}'"
        deltaQuery="SELECT discussion_id FROM adda_discussion WHERE discussion_date > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}' ">

        <field column="discussion_id" name="id" />
        <field column="discussion_text" name="content" stripHTML="true"/>
        <field column="discussion_date" name="created_date"/>

              <entity name="topic" pk="topic_id"
                    query="SELECT 
                        *, 'forum' AS type, CONCAT('forum-', topic_id) AS global_id
                        FROM adda_topic WHERE topic_id='${discussion.discussion_topic_id}'"
                    deltaQuery="SELECT topic_id FROM adda_topic WHERE topic_start_date > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"                     
                    parentDeltaQuery="SELECT discussion_topic_id FROM adda_discussion WHERE discussion_topic_id = '${topic.topic_id}'"> 

                      <field column="global_id" name="global_id" />
                       <field column="topic_id" name="parent_id"/>
                       <field column="topic_apt_id" name="apt_id"/>
                       <field column="topic_owner_id" name="owner_id"/>
                       <field column="type" name="type"/>          
                       <field column="topic_name" name="title"/>                       
                       <field column="topic_filter_level" name="filter_level"/>
              </entity>
    </entity>
```

Another point to note is that i had to group all messages together having the same topic_id using solr grouping so that you get only one result per topic.

The docs really need to be improved, It does not mention much.

Hope this helps a wandering soul in the future. :)